# Auth guard [admin] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Hello i am new to laravel i am following a tutorial to make admin page when i used admin auth guard but when i tried to access admin page "www.school.dev/admin"  i saw this error
[image]

This is my **config/auth.php**

```
    <?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    ],

];
```

**Admin Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'job_title',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**Admin Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('backend.dashboard');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'Frontend\HomeController@index');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Admin Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Auth::routes();

Route::get('admin', 'Backend\AdminController@index');



Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

**app/Http/kernel.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please run `composer dump-autoload` maybe it will solve your issue

Comment: You've accidentally pasted the Admin Model under the Admin Controller heading

Comment: Could be that the guard name is incorrect in your Admin Model. protected $guard = 'admin';? Try 'admins'?

Comment: @Buglinjo i just userd composer dump-autoload nothing change

Comment: @Toby Meller thank you i just edited the post and i tried changing guard name in the model to protected $guard = 'admins'; but nothing changed the same error remains it is caused by the controller public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('auth:admin');
 }

Comment: @YasserMoussa What is your Middleware looking like? Middleware > Kernel.php

Comment: Ok i just added kernel.php code at the end of the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142767/discussion-between-toby-mellor-and-yasser-moussa).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Clear the config cache `php artisan config:clear` or rebuild it `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: This actually fixed my problem thank you :D but  don't understand how could this happen i mean is there like caching system ON that even if i had an old error it will remain still until i remove cache and can i turn this off instead on using this command again and again?

Comment: auth guard [user] is not defined not working for me @lagbox

Answer (score 2):

This error message typically occurs when you are trying to use an authentication guard that has not been defined in your Laravel application's configuration. To resolve this error, you will need to define the "admin" guard in your application's "auth.php" configuration file.

Here are the steps you can follow:

Open the "config/auth.php" file in your Laravel application.
Scroll down to the "guards" array, and add a new guard for "admin"